# Get SQL results from another query that has many results and count how many results

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a database table with columns `IDS` and `Date`. I need to know if there are a certain number of rows (the number predetermined from another table) that meet the criteria of being between each week within a range of a larger span. Lets say '2021-11-29' and '2022-03-01' (In this case 12 weeks). So that the result would look something like this.

[image]

I am using this code to get the `DayStart` and `DayEnd`:

```
declare @STARTDATE date;
declare @ENDDATE date;

set @STARTDATE = '2021-11-29';
set @ENDDATE = '2022-03-01';

with Nums as
(
    select 1 as NN
    union all
    select NN + 1 as NN
    from Nums
    where NN < 1000
)
select  
    dateadd(dd, NN, @STARTDATE) as DayStart, 
    dateadd(dd, NN + 6, @STARTDATE) as DayEnd
from 
    Nums
where 
    dateadd(dd, NN + 6, @STARTDATE) <= @ENDDATE
    and datepart(dw, dateadd(dd, NN, @STARTDATE)) = 1 
option (maxrecursion 0)
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated

Comment: As per the question guide, please do not post images of code, data, error messages, etc. - copy or type the text into the question. Please reserve the use of images for diagrams or demonstrating rendering bugs, things that are impossible to describe accurately via text.

Comment: Please show the sample data that would generate your desired results.

Answer (score 0):

If I'm understanding your question correctly, if you have @STARTDATE and @ENDDATE set already you could do something like this:

```
SELECT SUM(CASE WHEN Date BETWEEN @STARTDATE AND @ENDDATE THEN 1 ELSE 0) END AS RowCount
```

That should return the number of rows in that table that are between the date range you pass into your start and end dates.

Answer (score 0):

What I chose to use a CTE table like the one above to get the date ranges I was looking for, cross joining them with the details that I needed to pull out of the data and then I used Count and left join to put it all together into one neat table.

Initially I was having trouble with cross join because it would only show the date ranges that had more than 0 rows. Because if it had 0 rows, there was nothing to cross join to. Left Join did the trick. I just had to left join on the range e.g. date>= DayStart and date<= DayEnd